# Have there been any papers on a relativistic relative state ("MWI") interpretation of QM with continuous spectra?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, quantum-interpretations

I've read the original papers on the relative state interpretation ("MWI") of Quantum Mechanics. They seem compelling, but they only addressed a nonrelativistic system and operators with discrete spectra. What has been done for relativistic systems, operators with continuous spectra, or both?

Comment: Which  original papers?

Comment: I'm referring to the papers in https://press.princeton.edu/titles/437.html, The Many Worlds Interpretation of Quantum Mechanics, edited by Bryce Seligman Dewitt & Neill Graham; I haven't read Everett's dissertation.

Comment: Most papers on MWI deal with, for example, the x-basis (which of course has a continuous spectrum), in particular because the x-basis is loosely speaking the "decoherence basis", and therefore has particular importance.